# Normal behaviour that app.component.ts OnInit is called 11 times?

Tags: angular

I have a project where i need to detect route changes. Therefore i edited my app.component.ts so that it will react on router changes with this function:

**app.component.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
        this.router.events.pipe(distinctUntilChanged((previous: any, current: any) => {
            console.log('test');
            if(current instanceof NavigationEnd) {
                return previous.url === current.url;
            }
            return true;
        })).subscribe((x: any) => {
            gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-2', {'page_path': x.url, 'anonymize_ip': true});
        });
    }
```

So when i now navigate between pages, `console.log('test');` is triggerd 11 times. Is this normal and if yes, where does it come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to `filter()` instead of `distinctUntilChanged()`. The *distinctUntilChanged* operator is used to remove duplicate values from a stream.

There will be no duplicates in the router events, but the router emits multiple events per route change. The number of events can vary depending on how many *resolvers* you have, because each resolver emits a pair of events.

```
@Component({..})
public MyComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    // ......
    private _destroyed: Subject<void> = new Subject();
    public ngOnDestroy() {
        this._destroyed.next();
        this._destroyed.complete();
    }
    public ngInit() {
        this.router.events.pipe(
           filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
           takeUntil(this._destroyed)
        ).subscribe(event => {
            gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-2', {'page_path': x.url, 'anonymize_ip': true});
        });
    }
}
```

Also *unsubscribe* from observables, because you'll leak memory otherwise. The above uses *takeUntil()* as an example way.